# I'm taking a picture, but it doesn't display in recyclerview

Tags: imageview, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a screen that when someone click in a button appear a AlertDialog, and user can choose take a picture or choose from gallery. The code of gallery is working good, but the another isn't. 
The idea is take a picture and display in a recyclerview.
Bellow I'll post the code:

```
public class NovoConteudoActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private RecyclerView recyclerViewAddImage;
    private ImageButton buttonAddNewImage;
    private List<Imagem> listImagens = new ArrayList<>();
    private AdapterImagem adapter;
    private Imagem imagemConfigurada;
    private ImageView imageDimension;
    String currentImagePath = null;

    private String[] permissoesNecessarias = new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    };

    private static final int SELECAO_CAMERA = 100;
    private static final int SELECAO_GALERIA = 200;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo_conteudo);

        //Inicializar Componentes:
        inicalizarComponentes();

        //Validar Permissões:
        Permissao.validarPermissoes(permissoesNecessarias, this, 1);

        //Set Adapter:
        adapter = new AdapterImagem(listImagens, this);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerViewAddImage.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerViewAddImage.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewAddImage.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Evento de clique no Botão para adicionar imagem:
        buttonAddNewImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                criarAlertDialog();
            }
        });
}

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        recyclerViewAddImage.smoothScrollToPosition(listImagens.size());

        if (listImagens.size() >= 6){
            buttonAddNewImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            buttonAddNewImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void inicalizarComponentes() {
        recyclerViewAddImage = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewAddImage);
        buttonAddNewImage = findViewById(R.id.buttonAddNewImage);
        imageDimension = findViewById(R.id.imageDimension);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public void criarAlertDialog(){

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Escolha uma opção");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout linearLayoutVertical = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayoutVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayoutVertical.setLayoutParams(params);

        TextView textCamera = new TextView(this);
        textCamera.setText("Tirar foto");
        textCamera.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_photo_camera_black_24dp, 0,0,0);
        textCamera.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
        textCamera.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textCamera.setLayoutParams(params);
        textCamera.setPadding(16,16,10,16);
        linearLayoutVertical.addView(textCamera);


        TextView textGaleria = new TextView(this);
        textGaleria.setText("Escolher Existente...");
        textGaleria.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_photo_black_24dp, 0,0,0);
        textGaleria.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
        textGaleria.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textGaleria.setLayoutParams(params);
        textGaleria.setPadding(16,10,10,16);
        linearLayoutVertical.addView(textGaleria);


        TextView textCancelar = new TextView(this);
        textCancelar.setText("Cancelar");
        textCancelar.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_close_cinza_24dp, 0,0,0);
        textCancelar.setCompoundDrawablePadding(5);
        textCancelar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textCancelar.setLayoutParams(params);
        textCancelar.setPadding(16,10,10,16);
        linearLayoutVertical.addView(textCancelar);

        alertDialog.setView(linearLayoutVertical);

        final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
        dialog.show();

        textCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File imageFile = null;
                    try {
                        imageFile = getImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (imageFile != null){
                        Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(NovoConteudoActivity.this,
                                "com.gustavo.android.fileprovider",
                                imageFile);
                        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                        startActivityForResult(i, SELECAO_CAMERA);
                    }
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        textGaleria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    startActivityForResult(i, SELECAO_GALERIA);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        textCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bitmap imagem = null;
            try {
                switch (requestCode){
                    case SELECAO_CAMERA:
                        rotateImage(setReducedImageSize());
                        break;

                    case SELECAO_GALERIA:
                        Uri localImagemSelecionada = data.getData();
                        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(localImagemSelecionada);
                        imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        if (imagem!= null){
                            imagemConfigurada = new Imagem();
                            imagemConfigurada.setImagem(imagem);
                            listImagens.add(imagemConfigurada);
                            Log.d("Imagem", "onActivityResult: " + listImagens);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }


    private File getImageFile()throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        currentImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private Bitmap setReducedImageSize(){
        int targetImageViewWidth = imageDimension.getWidth();
        int targetImageViewHeight = imageDimension.getHeight();

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentImagePath, bmOptions);

        int cameraImageWidth = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int cameraImageHeight = bmOptions.outHeight;

        int scaleFactor = Math.min(cameraImageWidth/targetImageViewWidth, cameraImageHeight/targetImageViewHeight);
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(currentImagePath, bmOptions);

    }

    private void rotateImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        ExifInterface exifInterface = null;

        try {
            exifInterface = new ExifInterface(currentImagePath);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation){
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(270);
                break;
            default:
        }
        Bitmap imageRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        if (imageRotate!= null){
            imagemConfigurada = new Imagem();
            imagemConfigurada.setImagem(imageRotate);
            listImagens.add(imagemConfigurada);
            Log.d("Lista", "rotateImage: " + listImagens);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        for (int permissaoResultado: grantResults){
            if (permissaoResultado == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                alertaValidacaoPermissao();
            }
        }

    }

    private void alertaValidacaoPermissao(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Permissões Negadas");
        builder.setMessage("Para utilizar o app é necessário aceitar as permissões");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

}
```

Bellow the code of adapter:

```
public class AdapterImagem extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterImagem.MyViewHolder> {

    List <Imagem> list;
    Context context;

    public AdapterImagem(List<Imagem> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_add_photo, parent, false);
        return new AdapterImagem.MyViewHolder(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Imagem imagem = list.get(position);
        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(imagem.getImagem())
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.newImagem);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView newImagem;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            newImagem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newImage);

        }
    }

}
```

And the Class Imagem:

```
public class Imagem {

    private Bitmap imagem;

    public Imagem() {
    }

    public Imagem(Bitmap imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }

    public Bitmap getImagem() {
        return imagem;
    }

    public void setImagem(Bitmap imagem) {
        this.imagem = imagem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting an adapter with an empty list.

instead of initializing the adapter here:

```
    //don't initialize here
    adapter = new AdapterImagem(listImagens, this);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);
    .........
```

instead initialize here:

```
 case SELECAO_GALERIA:
                    Uri localImagemSelecionada = data.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(localImagemSelecionada);
                    imagem = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    if (imagem!= null){
                        imagemConfigurada = new Imagem();
                        imagemConfigurada.setImagem(imagem);
                        listImagens.add(imagemConfigurada);

                        //here
                        adapter = new AdapterImagem(listImagens,this);

                        //also set the adapter here
                         recyclerViewAddImage.setAdapter(adapter);

                        Log.d("Imagem", "onActivityResult: " + listImagens);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    break;
```